# Issue in jdbcadapter with log4j

Tags: java, sqlite, jboss, log4j

Following is my `jdbcAdapter` and I am working with jboss server, I have given my `sqlite` database location as static, I want to give that location in dynamic.

```
<appender name="jdbcAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
        <param name="URL" value="jdbc:sqlite:D:/db/sfLog.db" />
        <param name="user" value="" />
        <param name="password" value="" />
        <param name="driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
        <param name="threshold" value="trace" />
        <param name="sql" value="INSERT INTO sfLog(UserID,UserName,IPAddress,Port,UserAgent,Type,Status,Message,Date) VALUES ('%X{UserID}','%X{UserName}','%X{IP}','%X{Port}','%X{Agent}','%X{Type}','%X{Status}','%m','%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}')" />
</appender>
```

Where as my other sqlite metadata follows my getting `file.getAbsolutePath();` , how can I do that using `log4j`?

Thanks in Advances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try setting these params in **properties-service.xml** and then read the params using `System.getProperty`